# How to use Ajax with Jquery and checkbox

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii2

i am trying a simple program where I select a checkbox and then based on the checkbox selected a value is displayed using AJAX. this is my code

```
<form action=""> 
<label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="4" id="check4" class="ajax">Module4</label>
</form>
<div class="col-md-5">
    <div id="value">
         <h2>Selected Module</h2>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
jQuery(".ajax").click(function(e){
    var val=jQuery('#check4').val();
    //~ alert(val);return false;
     jQuery.post("<?php echo \Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl(['cart/function2'])?>&id="+val) 
        .done(function(data) {
            if (data.trim().length >0)
            {
            alert("hai");   
             jQuery("#value").html(data);

            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

All I get is a

> Bad Request (#400): Unable to verify your data submission.

And the controller function code is as follows

```
public function actionFunction2($id)
    {


        return $this->renderAjax("function2");
    }
```

The view file contains a line of code

```
<?php 
echo "Hai you have selected module 4";
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have a really dirty code. Buddy

Comment: CSRF validation ?? Try disabling your CSRF validation and check if issue persists !!!

Comment: @let me see i tried but still i got 400

Comment: @AjithN why you need to use ajax you can create it without it so is there in special scenario.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @LET ME SEE i tried like this and it worked

```
public function beforeAction($action) 
{
    $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

i disabled the csrf validation. 
i have a question how did u know that csrf validation was the issue? @ Let me see

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax like this:

```
$.post("./phppage.php",{checkbox: $("#checkboxID").is(":checked")},function(data,status){
    // use data for the returned value
});
```

And you can access the posted value in php like this:

```
<?php
     echo $_POST['checkbox'];
?>
```

Comment: The big problem was bad coding. This way he can debug the code much easier